# excessive HTTP 500 when querying graph.microsoft.com for calendar events

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am seeing the following error in Europe(It woks fine in North America) for my get calendar events call in Microsoft Graph API.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {fo...'.
```

couple of weeks ago I got a different error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Root configuration found at: Root</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdan...'.
```

In both the cases it was HTTP 500 back from Microsoft.

Updated on Jun 12:

Hi David,
Here are the request IDs and appropriate timestamps.

```
2018/05/24 4:30:01.080 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-147   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=c5ba4598-eedf-4705-920b-0dcbdb09d6e1
2018/05/24 4:30:00.552 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-285)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=6fd4ad1c-4e94-4233-93aa-3eaf9413c9fc
2018/05/24 4:29:59.454 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-115)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=9711568a-3eb1-452c-ad01-1325535cfc24
2018/05/24 4:29:59.977 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-78)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=5a9d5071-9bcf-40a3-ad79-dab0c28d26b2
2018/05/24 4:29:59.977 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-78)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=5a9d5071-9bcf-40a3-ad79-dab0c28d26b2
2018/05/24 4:29:59.752 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-20)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=b79765d9-d71b-4b87-8cb3-b3cde4315edb
2018/05/24 4:29:58.745 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-143)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=b1ad3fa1-9b30-4f4d-ad9f-01ae4766ce50
2018/05/24 4:29:58.708 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-276)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=125f6382-8adb-4031-bac4-1f4fa97110bf
2018/05/24 4:29:58.697 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-215)   […]   InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=a1376dc8-a2cd-4c69-8b01-5290ab109fb7
2018/05/24 4:29:58.922 UTC [ERROR] (pool-79-thread-64)   […]    InternalServerErrorException while executing GET with client-request-id=6f14fb20-9dbd-44c1-aa66-1135a40e10fe
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the following response headers for your failed requests?  UTC time, request-id, X-BEServer?

That would help us see what actually happened on the server.

Comment: Hi David,
Here are the request IDs and appropriate timestamps. I updated the question with all the info